# Match and decode base64 values in a file in python

Tags: python, base64

I have file, **a.txt** which has content like this

```
dn: cn=user,o=abc
changetype: add
nrfLastNotificationTime: 6253451636514
srvprvUserPrefsPlus:: sytdrrr65mVyc2lvbhgsf56a56sda6rtGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPzuysdyfs765==
srvprvUUID: hsfytf5e5
uid: 654sfdg
givenName: stdftst
fullName: ytfsdytsfty
```

I am looking to parse this file and decode the base64 values if existed.
for example **srvprvUserPrefsPlus** attribute has base64 value.

i have tried this code,

```
import re
import base64
obj_list =  []
with open('a.txt', 'r') as input_file:
 s = line.split(":",1)

 temp_dict = {}

 k=s[0].strip()
 v=s[1].strip()
 if re.match(r'^(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*(?:[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)?$',v):
  v1 = base64.b64decode(v)
  v2 = str(v1).encode("utf-8")
  temp_dict.update({k:v2})
  obj_list.append(temp_dict)
  temp_dict={}
 else:
  temp_dict.update({k:v})
  obj_list.append(temp_dict)
  temp_dict={}

with open('b.txt',"w") as f1:
    for obj in obj_list:
        for k, v in obj.items():
            f1.write(str(k))
            f1.write(':')
            f1.write(str(v))
            f1.write("\n")
        f1.write("\n")
```

but it is not working as expected, what needs to be improved here.

Comment: Why bother using that complicated regex instead of just `r'[A-Za-z0-9+/]+=?=?'`? It's not as though the `base64` module cares how long the regex is.

Comment: i was able to solve it by adding **:\s**  after **^** in regex.  the expected decoded value is **<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><properties/>\n"** but i am getting **b'b\'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><properties/>\\n\''** what are those extra b's there